# Unknown CRS for CAD (.dxf) data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing, cad

I have a .dwg/.dxf file that needs to be georeferenced so I can draw some boundaries on a site in Indianapolis, Indiana, USA. I'm using GQIS 3.18.2, only the .dxf file will be imported. Now when imported, the data shows up as the map figure as a whole (reading the legend etc. as data). This is floating in space. Under layer properties, I can view the extent as (-362.3947145426504903,-998.1682020468679184 : 2891.9386173585958204,1472.8011332957680679). I've tried playing around with the "brute force" method but cannot seem to land on the right one.

[image: full extent showing data in center of map, where its supposed to be in Indiana, USA] [image: .dxf file imported to QGIS, after setting CRS at WGS 84/Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857) for all layers and map.]

[image: original .dxf file]

Answer (score 2):

The CAD drawing seems to use a local coordiante system with meters or feet as units. Furthermore, the map is rotated, because 56th East Street stretches East-West and Drum street North-South.

Best choice would be to ask the author of the drawing what coordinate origin they have used, and what units of measurement.

A brute force method would be to georeference the creek against aerial photos, but I assume the creek is not drawn exactly enough for that.